# Highlight duplicate value cells dynamically

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have stored numbers in nine rows and nine columns.

When I select a particular cell I want to highlight all cells with same value e.g. if I select cell having value 8 all cells having value 8 should be highlighted.

Then if I select cell having value 5 all cells having value 5 should be highlighted instead cells having value 8.

Comment: Sounds like a job for VBA. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

A small VBA macro to update all colors everytime a new cell is selected. It compares the value of the selected cell with all other cell values and if they match, the compared cell is highlighted in yellow.

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal rngSel As Range)
  Set rngTable = [B2:E13]
  If rngSel.Count > 1 Or Intersect(rngSel, rngTable) Is Nothing Then End
  For Each rngCell In rngTable
    rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(rngCell.Value = rngSel.Value, 27, -4142)
  Next
End Sub
```

#### Tips

- `Set rngTable = [B2:E13]` » Change the range of cells where colors are allowed to be changed
- `IIf(rngCell.Value = rngSel.Value, 27, -4142)` » Change the [color code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc296089%28v=office.12%29.aspx) if you want another color to be used

[image]